# Inner Class and Constructors

Tags: java, constructor, inner-classes

I want to create a class , which will have the same inner one , to be more specific something like this :

```
class PassengerComponent extends PlaneComponent
{   
   PassengerComponent InnerPC ;
   int inner ; // checks if PassengerComponent has an inner class
```

The passengerComponent inherits from :

```
class PlaneComponent
{
   String Description ;
}
```

The problem is that the inner class should be filled randomly , which means
sometimes the passenger component will have an inner one and sometimes not!
The way I am trying to do it , is the following :

```
        int random = (int )(Math.random() * 1 + 0 );
        if( random == 0)
        {
           PassengerComponent PC1 = new PassengerComponent("Passenger Component #1" , 0);    
        }
        else
        {
           PassengerComponent PC1 = new PassengerComponent("Passenger Component #1" , 1); 
        }

       PC1.ready_check(Sc, Cg);
```

While the passenger constructor is the following :

```
    public PassengerComponent( String D , int i)
    {
      Description = D ;
      System.out.println( " PassengerComponent: " + Description + " Has Been Created ");
      switch (i) {
        case 0:
            InnerPC = new PassengerComponent( " Inner Passenger Component #1 " , 2 );
            inner = 1 ;
            break;
        case 1:
            inner = 0 ;
            break ;
        case 2:
            break;
        default:
            break;
       }
    }
  }
```

The constructors are called and the output messages seems to be ok , but when PC1.ready_check is being called , compiler cant find PC1 , which i created ! (ready_check dont have any problems for anyone wondering)

Sorry for long question , any ideas ?

Comment: Why are you using magic numbers (0 and 1) to represent if it has an inner? In this case, its binary, so a Boolean `hasInner` is fine, but id still much prefer an Enum for the type safety and the expandability. Plus, while were at it, lets change that switch statement to make use of Maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with inner classes or `PassengerComponent`, only with variable scope.

Since `PC1` is declared **inside** the `if/else` block, it's only known within this block.

If you want to use `PC1` after the `if/else` block, declare it one level above:

```
int random = (int )(Math.random() * 1 + 0 );
PassengerComponent PC1;
if( random == 0)
{
    PC1 = new PassengerComponent("Passenger Component #1" , 0);    
}
else
{
    PC1 = new PassengerComponent("Passenger Component #1" , 1); 
}

PC1.ready_check(Sc, Cg);
```

Comment: @SocialProgrammer If it solved your problem, don't forget to accept this answer.